# No-reply address in Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-2003

In Exchange 2003 and later, is it possible to create a ”no-reply” address? E.g. let’s say I have the address *noreply@example.com* and I want Exchange to discard every singly mail sent to it.

In the Unix world, both [Postfix](http://forums.devshed.com/mail-server-help-111/postfix-send-mail-to-dev-null-howto-362743.html) and [Exim](http://diehn.net/blog/2006/08/exim4-and-routing-message-to-devnull/) seem to be able to achieve this by routing mail to /dev/null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a distribution group with `noreply@example.com' as its address.
- Add no members to the group.

Answer (score 0):

On Exchange 2003 if noreply@example.com is a mailbox address you can use outlook or owa to create a mailbox rule. with mailbox rules you can permanently delete mails send to an address.
Since Exchange 2007 you can use Transport Rules in the Exchange Config. Powershell or Exchange GUI (run's Powershell Command in the Background) to create a rule in order to delete these Mails